# How to check values inside a List? I'm going to use it inside if statement

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check if the List field Amount is not equal to 0.

Tried this below and it is obvious that it is not possible. Are there any other ways to execute my logic?

```
if(listItems.Values.Select(x=> x.Amount !=0))
{
      //code
}
```

I want to print List values that has Amount != 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are looking for `Any()` to see if any element matches the condition like below. As well instead of `!=` you may want to check for greater than condition (considering there is no negative value in your said list)

```
if(listItems.Values.Any(x => x.Amount > 0))
{
      //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the where clause to get those that their amount is not zero:

```
var result = listItems.Values.Where(x=> x.Amount !=0)
```

then:

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
    //do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may help?:

```
 foreach (item in list)
 {
     if (item != 0)
     //code
 }
```

Comment: Please explain why this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .Any for boolean return

```
if (listItems.Values.Any(x=> x.Amount !=0))
{
}
```

For Printing Them to the console.

```
listItems.Values.Where(x => x.Amount !=0).ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x.Amount));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the items with `Amount != 0` with `Where` clause and then check the `Count()`:

```
var resultList = listItems.Values.Where(x => x.Amount != 0);
if(resultList.Count() > 0)
{
   //do what you want
}
```

Comment: Better: use the `Count` method that accepts a delegate as parameter: `if(listItems.Values.Count(x => x.Amount != 0) > 0) { }`

Comment: @SebastianHofmann the OP need the items on the list after the filtering, so it's better to use `Where`

Comment: Oh, I see. In this case, I'd use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`.

Comment: `Any()` only returns `bool` and then it still need to filter the list again to get the result